# Electron React app white screen + disconnected devtools in build but fine in development?

Tags: reactjs, electron, devtools, electron-builder

When I run my app on the development server (npm start) it works fine without any issues in the console.

However, when I build my app (npm run build && electron-builder -m) I get a white screen and disconnected devTools.

Here is my main.js file

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, screen } = require('electron')

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const { width, height } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    title:"DSL viewer",
    width:1050,
    height:700,
    maxHeight:height,
    maxWidth:width,
    minHeight:700,
    minWidth:1050,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      devTools: true
    }
  })

  win.loadURL('./index.html');
  
  win.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Here is a screenshot of what the app looks like[image]

Does anyone know what may be causing this or how I can go about debugging it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Buddy did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It is because electron is unable to find the index.html after build. Change  window.loadURL to  window.loadURL(__dirname+"/index.html").